# Adding in a CASE WHEN condition in a Jaccard Similarity query for Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have another Jaccard similarity-related question to ask:

As the previous method I tried (calling the jaccard similarity algorithm) gave me strange results (I'll ask the continuation of that question in another thread):

I tried another method to calculate the jaccard similarity of my test data representation (as follows):

CSV used to create all title nodes:

```
title_id,title  
T1,Article Title 1  
T2,Article Title 2
```

CSV that I want to use to create the relationships:

```
title_id,keyword_id,keyword  
T1,K1,aaa  
T1,K2,bbb  
T1,K3,ccc  
T1,K4,ddd  
T2,K1,aaa  
T2,K5,eee  
T2,K6,fff  
T2,K4,ddd
```

I was able to calculate the jaccard similarity using the code below:

```
MATCH(t:Title)-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(k:Keyword)<-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]-(other:Title)  
WITH t, other, 
     count(k) AS intersection, 
     collect(k) AS i  
MATCH (t)-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(tk:Keyword)  
WITH t, other, intersection, i, 
     collect(tk) AS s1  
MATCH (other)-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(ok:Keyword)  
WITH t, other, intersection, i, s1, 
     collect(ok) AS s2  
WITH t, other, intersection, s1, s2  
WITH t, other, intersection, s1, s2,
     s1+filter(x IN s2 WHERE NOT x IN s1) AS union
RETURN t.title, other.title, s1,s2, 
      ((1.0*intersection)/SIZE(union)) AS jaccard   
ORDER BY jaccard DESC LIMIT 100
```

However, I would like to also set a cutoff point for recommendations I would make based on this similarity.
I attempted to add in a CASE WHEN limitation (as follows):

```
...  
RETURN t, other, s1,s2, 
       CASE WHEN ((1.0*intersection)/size(union)) > 0.1 
         THEN s2.jaccard 
         ELSE null
       END AS jaccard  
...
```

After some trying, I understood that I needed to add a ...node(?) in front of the THEN ... jaccard ELSE ... bit, but when I do that, while the code runs, the jaccard column is all filled with null.

As I'm not too sure what to call this exact problem of mine, If anyone would be able to point me towards some basic documents to read over and understand what I got wrong, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: You can use neo4j-graph-algorithms to calculate Jaccard index.
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity-jaccard/

Comment: Not very clear what you want to get. Discard the results for which the Jacquard measure is less than the threshold value?

Comment: @TomažBratanič: I tried that previously, but as my results turned out funny, I decided to try another way to calculate the Jaccard index..

Comment: @stdob--: I'm trying to achieve what the similarity cutoff does in the jaccard index algorithm...